# How can we store values getting from user in array in shell/bash scripts?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have some input element and i want to store them in array . I don't no the limit of element .

```
Suppose the elements are like 

one
two
three
four
five
six
```

The input size can be different.

i tried it like

```
declare -a array 

read -a array

echo ${array[@]}
```

but it only print first element. How can i print all values ?

I finally solve it

My code: (https://ideone.com/sy5NQh)

```
#!/bin/bash
# your code goes here
declare -a array
i=0
while read -r input; do
    array[$i]=$input
    ((i++))
done

echo ${array[@]}
```

Comment: I just test your code and works for me:
    xxx@rosseta:/tmp$ read -a array
    one true three
    xxx@rosseta:/tmp$ echo ${array[@]}
    one true three
    xxx@rosseta:/tmp$  echo ${array[2]}
    three

Comment: @d1egoaz: it print all values ??

Comment: How are you inputting the values to `read`? `read -a` splits a single line into an array it doesn't read multiple lines.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 is probably of some use here.

Comment: @EtanReisner: how can i read all values ?

Comment: @EtanReisner: Thanks etan it is useful for me :)

Comment: @SAC Yes, https://asciinema.org/a/17102

Comment: @d1egoaz Oh the suspense ... Three minutes to show what can be shown in three seconds?

Comment: Also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005 and in particular the `mapfile` hint if you have Bash 4.

Comment: upvoted, since this is actually a very good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It works for me

```
declare -a array
i=0
while read -r input; do
    array[$i]=$input
    ((i++))
done

echo ${array[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing it this wat will allow you to simply add the array as arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$1" != "" ]
do
        array+=("$1")
        shift
done

echo "${array[@]}"
exit
```

Comment: No need for the count just use `array+=("$1")` to append.

Comment: very tidy! I had forgotten about that :-)